# Mockito and Javax annotation @PostConstruct

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm writing a Java unit test using JUnit Jupiter for a class which has a method with a `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` annotation.

I want to test a method in the class but am hitting an issue where the `@PostConstruct` method is always called once the object is created (unsurprisingly). The Mockito mock object I've created to be used in the `@PostConstruct` method isn't providing the results I require.

Here's the method that is being called when the object is created:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyService {
    @Inject
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    private Integer myId;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postInit() {
        MyObject myObj = myRepository.findByName("FOO");
        myId = myObj.getId();
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        ... code to be tested here...
    }
}
```

My JUnit test class contains the following:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class MyServiceTest {
    private static final Integer ID = 0;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        // Given.
        MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
        myObj.setId(ID);

        MyRepository myRepository = Mockito.mock(MyRepository.class);
        Mockito.when(myRepository.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(myObj);

        // Test runs here.
        myService.myMethod()
    }
}
```

When I run the unit test, I can see that the mock has been instantiated via my IDE. However, it always returns a NULL object when the `findByName("FOO")` method is called, even though it should return a correct instance of `MyObject`.

As such, the unit test fails with a NullPointerException because `myObj` is null.

Is there anything obviously incorrect that I'm doing here>?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: How do you expect `myRepository` to appear in your `MyService` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your test slightly, creating `MyService` via `Mockito` and making `myMethod` return the id:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyServiceTest {
    private static final Integer ID = 42;

    @InjectMocks
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        // Given.
        MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
        myObj.setId(ID);

        MyRepository myRepository = Mockito.mock(MyRepository.class);
        Mockito.when(myRepository.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(myObj);

        // Test runs here.
        assertThat(myService.myMethod()).isEqualTo(ID);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.myId" is null

    at MyService.myMethod(MyService.java:24)
    at MyServiceTest.myTest(MyServiceTest.java:28)
    ...
```

So clearly our mocking of `findByName` hasn't worked.

That's because `myRepository` is just a local variable in our test -- there's nothing to get it injected into `MyService`.

One way to fix this is not to use spring test infrastructure, just plain  Mockito. We use the standard @Mock/@InjectMocks annotations to create our mock and the object we are testing. The drawback here is that we must remember to call `postInit` ourselves:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyServiceTest {
    private static final Integer ID = 42;

    @Mock
    MyRepository myRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        // Given.
        MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
        myObj.setId(ID);

        Mockito.when(myRepository.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(myObj);
        myService.postInit();
        // Test runs here.
        assertThat(myService.myMethod()).isEqualTo(ID);
    }
}
```

To use Spring to call postInit you can do this: (I'm not sure if there's a more idiomatic way to create the mock MyRepository instance)

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyService.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyServiceTest.Configuration.class})
class MyServiceTest {
    @TestConfiguration
    static class Configuration {
        @Bean
        public MyRepository myRepository() {
            MyRepository myRepository = mock(MyRepository.class);
            MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
            myObj.setId(ID);
            Mockito.when(myRepository.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(myObj);
            return myRepository;
        }
    }
    private static final Integer ID = 42;
    
    @Autowired
    MyService myService;
    
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        assertThat(myService.myMethod()).isEqualTo(ID);
    }
}
```

One way to avoid using `@SpringBootTest` is to create the `MyService` instance in our test configuration (I've converted it to constructor injection too):

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyServiceTest.Configuration.class})
class MyServiceTest {
    @TestConfiguration
    static class Configuration {
        @Bean
        public MyRepository myRepository() {
            MyRepository myRepository = mock(MyRepository.class);
            MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
            myObj.setId(ID);
            Mockito.when(myRepository.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(myObj);
            return myRepository;
        }

        @Bean
        public MyService myService(MyRepository myRepository) {
            return new MyService(myRepository);
        }
    }
    private static final Integer ID = 42;

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        assertThat(myService.myMethod()).isEqualTo(ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's much better - thank you very much.